# Works on Simulator, doesn't work on the iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Here is my code.. why it isn't gonna add object to array when on device?
Maybe array can't be read from file?  I write file to documents directory, but what may be wrong? THanks...

```
if (contactsToProcess==nil)
    {
    contactsToProcess=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Array with objs initialized");
    }
    contactsToProcess=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fPath()];
    [contactsToProcess addObject:cont];
    NSLog(@"Object added to file:");
    for(Contact *cn in contactsToProcess)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", cn.fName);
    }

        [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:contactsToProcess toFile:fPath()];
```

fPath() does:

```
NSString* PathforResources(NSString* filename)
{
    NSString *leftpart=[filename stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString *extension=[filename pathExtension];
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:leftpart ofType:extension];

}
NSString* DocumentsDirectory()
{
    NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDirectory, YES);
    return [paths objectAtIndex:0];

}
NSString* fPath()
{
    return [DocumentsDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"quickdial.xml"];
}
```

Comment: The first 5 lines (`if contactsToProcess == nil {...}`) are useless, as you re-assign `contactsToProcess` on the 6th line.

Comment: What is the path returned by `fPath()`?

Comment: It returns paths to Documents directory:NSString* PathforResources(NSString* filename)
{
 NSString *leftpart=[filename stringByDeletingPathExtension];
 NSString *extension=[filename pathExtension];
 return [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:leftpart ofType:extension];
 
}
NSString* DocumentsDirectory()
{
 NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDirectory, YES);
 return [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 
}
NSString* fPath()
{
 return [DocumentsDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"quickdial.xml"];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should change your code into:

```
contactsToProcess=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fPath()];
if (contactsToProcess==nil)
{
  contactsToProcess=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  NSLog(@"Array with objs initialized");
}
...
```

then everything should work. Some explanation: the code as you posted will only work as you expect if the file `quickdial.xml` is already present; it will be specifically unable to create the file with a proper content (or to create it at all, I don't know what is the exact effect of archiving a `nil` pointer). Indeed, when the file does not exist, after executing you original code:

```
if (contactsToProcess==nil)
{
contactsToProcess=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Array with objs initialized");
}
contactsToProcess=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:fPath()];
```

`contactsToProcess` will be nil; this means that all successive operation on it will have no effect and that you are archiving a `nil` pointer. I.e, when the file does not exist, it will not be created with the array as you expect. This is what happens on your device.

My hypothesis is that you ran the program in a different state on your simulator, and that your array got archived into the file successfully. Then you changed the program to the current state; on the simulator it keeps working because the file is there and contains an archived array. On the device the file is not created or just contains `nil`, so it does not work as you expect.

I would suggest removing the app from the device (tap on the app icon until you enter the dashboard editing mode, then tap on the delete button); then apply the change I suggested above and re-run.

Comment: How should I create a file properly on the device? I have a functions that on start-up checks if file there is the file in Documents direcory, if it doesn't exist, it is copied... strange... well.. thanks

Comment: it could depend on the content; if you archive `nil`, you will get `nil`. I would suggest removing the app from the device (prolonged tap on the app icon, then tap on the delete button), apply the change I suggested above and re-run.

Comment: isn't it working? would you give a try to my last code version? I changed a bit...

Answer (score 0):

What is the path returned by `fPath()`?

On Simulator you have access to the full file system *(at least as far as your logged in Mac OS X user can access)*, on device only to the sand-boxed home directory.

Also check for unmatched lower-/UPPER-case since the device file system is case sensitive, Mac OS X is not by default.

Comment: The sandbox is the home directory on device, so `~/` is a good starting point.

Comment: DOn't quite unerstand... how should I write filePath then?

Comment: @Vova Stajilov - I can not know unless you print out the full path that you are trying to write to. All I can do is guess at the most common problems people usually have. Your code for `fPath()` seems ok, so I would guess at missing file, or misnamed file, in documents folder.